# A term for victimiser's paranoia

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes the following feeling:

*Let me highlight the context in which I want to use this word* - Let us say, I have committed some wrong-doing to another party. Now I feel that whatever the other party does to me, it is because I have committed in the past some wrongs to them. Feelings may or may not be misplaced. Still I feel that way; this is more like a paranoia.

Paranoia, even though correct, is a very generic word. Does there exist a word/term precisely for Victimizer's fear of an impending comeuppance?

I cite two examples which have appeared in Geo-politics:

1. Japan's invasion of China in 1937 till the culmination of WW2 left many Chinese dead and led to permanent Chinese suspicion of Japan. Now, if China does something, Japan thinks it's because of the atrocities it committed in China which motivates chinese behaviour towards it.
2. Dr. Sashi Tharoor publised a book "Inglorious Empire" highlighting how British rule over India reduced India to one of the most poorest country on earth. Channel 4 news interviewed him and the interviewer said and I quote: *This is difficult stuff because Britain is just trying to do a big trade deal with you, we need your trade, so will you hold British colonism of India against us?*

Now, in both the cases the victimiser of yesteryears fear that their victims will choose to adopt a punitive posture towards them (China and India respectively), even though the victims have shown no such inclination. Now my question is that, does there exist some word or term for sucha paranoia?

Comment: Feelings are feelings, they can't be "wrong" or misplaced if you feel them vis-à-vis someone. Also, the *opposite* of a "victimisation complex" sounds like it would be about justification...sorry but that is a no-go.

Comment: I think, I have wrongly parapharased victimisation vomplex thing. Let me correct that.

Comment: The issue here is not if feelings are unfounded or have a basis. They can have a very strong basis, but that's besides the point. I am interested in a word/term specifically for the fear which a victimiser has for some sort of revenge by his victims.

Comment: victimizer's fear of revenge or retribution. There is no single word.

Comment: I posted this question after asking a lot of people. If there does exist such a word, may be someone will answer someday.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because single word requests should be accompanied by a contextual example of the intended use.

Comment: Why is the question being closed? @Greybeard claims that context is not given. Well, a clear context within a proper example is provided here, making it amply clear as to what exactly I am looking for. Looking at the comments/answers of people here, it's amply clear that people have taken the post in a meaningful way. Even though there may not be a proper word to encapsulate the sentiment, but where does the question qualify for a closure by giving a reason "This question does not appear to be about English language". The question should be reopened, so as to give chance to others.

Comment: The close voters really should have used the close reason we have which links to the [tag guidance](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info); this generic close reason was chosen because they close voted with a custom message ("requests should be accompanied by a contextual example of the intended use"). Adding an example sentence (where there's a blank where you would use the word) helps to prevent answers that make you say "in the context I am looking for, it doesn't help". As you edit, you should check the box so that it can be reviewed by other users.

Comment: @Laurel Well, in my understanding the context has to be posted in the Question, and I have done that there amply. The one line you have chosen to highlight "in the context I am looking for, it doesn't help" is a mere comment in response to the answer, and context is mentioned in the Question. Can a comment form the basis of a closure for the question?

Comment: @Laurel In response to the comment which doesn't have a context, you are asking me to Edit a Question which already has a context clearly mentioned. Actually Question is itself explained with an example providing a context. Where is the scope of an edit?

Comment: Can't we use the word **guilt** or **guilty conscience**?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thanks Yosef. Take 2nd example - British interviewer was guilty conscious of colonial past, and *consequently* fears that Indian govt will use it against British economic interests in India. Which word encapsulates this fear/paranoia of a victimiser? This fear/paranoia arising out of guilt.

Comment: Not sure this quest can ever be satisfied, but guilt has fear built-in. Not sorry you might get caught, but sorry your wrong brings inevitable punishment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions (No single word I could think of other than "ruefulness" suggested elsewhere)

- **Karmic dread**: the fear of bad karma or consequences coming back to haunt someone because of their past actions.
- **Retributive anxiety** or **Anticipatory reprisal fear/apprehension**: fear of the victims returning for revenge

---

- **Guilt-driven paranoia** (rejected)

Comment: Hej, Well *Karmic dread* was funny and catchy. Atleast it has my upvote!! Danke :)

Comment: *Guilt-driven paranoia* is not apt in the two contexts I mentioned in the question. As also alluded by @TimR below, the victimiser may not really fell guilty/contrite. He rues of having done wrong because he fells that the victim is in a position to take a punitive action.

Comment: @cph_sto - see update.

Comment: Both your suggestions were very apt. Though @FumbleFingers had suggested *retribution* but I wanted to avoid any preposition like *of* and *Retributive anxiety* fulfills that rather well. *Karmic dread* has a comic element intrinsic to it, but catchy. Many thanks.
PS: I presume you have a side devoted to literature. Would you recommend some good book that people should rerad in 2024? Many times random recommendations are actually the best ones :)

Comment: I can recommend the books of Stephen Fry: [Mythos, Heroes and Troy](https://amzn.to/42kYjSK) if you are into greek myths and history. For some truly spectacular and alternative SciFi, the oeuvre of [William Gibson](https://amzn.to/48R2GY4) in this order: Sprawl Trilogy. Neuromancer (1984) Count Zero (1986) Mona Lisa Overdrive (1988)
Bridge Trilogy. Virtual Light (1993) Idoru (1996) All Tomorrow's Parties (1999)
Blue Ant Trilogy. Pattern Recognition (2002) Spook Country (2006) Zero History (2010)
Jackpot Trilogy. The Peripheral (2014) Agency (2019) (Last is still being written)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not Greek Mythology or into Science Fictions, but more into contemporary history, psychology and motivational books. But, may be I should take a cue and start with one of the books from SciFi you have mentioned. Needless to say, I was right to think that your english horizons are rather broad :)

Comment: My parents gave me 10 James Bond books in English when I was 12. I read a minimum of one book a week until the Internet ruined my book reading. I however do sometimes pick up a book and finish it in a day or two if I am on vacation or something.
I just purchased [The Russo-Ukrainian War: The Return of History](https://amzn.to/3SdzROt) by Serhii Plokhy, but have not read it yet.

Comment: I checked your profile on stackoverflow as well. You have along history in IT sector. Excellent. From your profile I could glean that you are a prolific reader. It's clear from the writing style. Please accept my congratulations for that. Your parents inculcated a habit of reading at such an early age, and that's a life shaping thing. I have lately started reading some 3 years back on regular basis. A Ukrainian colleage here in Germany recommended me this book by Plokhy as well, and you just did that. The subject suits my interest as well. I will 100% complete this in 2024.

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity: If you read books so fast, how much are you able to retain what you have read? Or is it that you have read so much on that subject, that you can easily draw connection from your past readings making it easier to retain new Info. I am a very slow reader and can take a month to read a 250 page book easily, else can't retain much. That's why I was curious.

Comment: I learned very early to speed read. I retain most if not all if I am interested.
I read Dune in a week, but never managed to finish some of the later works.
The Hobbit: a day or two and the rest of the Rings less than a month.
Some books I read REALLY fast. Dan Brown for example. It is like junk food. I read "The Lost Symbol (600+ pages) in three sittings, so 6-7 hours in total.
William Gibson's "The Peripheral" is a VERY hard read. The reason is that Gibson writes in a very specific manner: he pretends you know what he is talking about but you do not until he reveals it later in the story

Comment: What an epiphany! I had precisely *The Da Vinci Code* by Dan Brown in my mind when I asked you this question. When this book was released, in 2004 I think, many people I knew read it within 2-3 days but I was not sure if they understood anything. I found their take on the subject rather inconsistent, as if they have skimmed through the book. Let's say, if you read this book by Serhii Plokhy, would you remember the year of any particular event mentioned there, or would you remember that event in passing? Won't you mess up the info at later stage, since there will be too much info to retain?

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but to ***(always) look over one's shoulder*** is to have a fear that something bad will happen to you, sometimes done in retaliation for another act. It captures the expectation and fear of something bad coming, which you are always on the lookout for. It doesn't necessarily imply that you did something to deserve it, but your own actions can be the reason why you expect retaliation.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt the *specific* fear OP asks about can be unambiguously encapsulated in a single English word. But it's worth noting that [Cambridge Dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/617861/a-term-for-victimisers-paranoia) actually has a dedicated entry for...

> **fear of retribution**
> *an unpleasant emotion or thought that you have when you are frightened or worried by something dangerous, painful, or bad that is happening or ...*

Fairly obviously, ***retribution*** implies that the fearful person (probably a "bully", in OP's case) is at least aware that *someone else* (the "victim" in OP's case) thinks he (the bully) perpetrated some "injustice" or "crime" for which punishment may be forthcoming.

---

It's still endlessly debated by literary critics, but my understanding of Orwell's *1984* is that by the end of the book, Winston Smith has been told that he *will* be shot with no advance warning, at some point in the future.

But the strange (from the average reader's perspective) thing about this final situation is that Smith *isn't* in "fear of retribution" (for his "subversive" affair with Julia). He's been successfully brainwashed into accepting his fate. So even though that fear doesn't *actually* exist, it's essential the reader has a clear concept of what "fear of retribution"  actually *means*, in order to understand the significance of its *absence.*

Comment: Well, fear of retribution would be a normal way to describe. I thought, may be there exists a word for this particular emotion. May be in English there isn't.

Comment: Well, if there *was* such a word, we'd expect it to be mentioned in that Cambridge entry. Or perhaps more likely, the Cambridge entry wouldn't exist in the first place, because we'd have no need for a preposition-based phrase if we had a single word.

Comment: I think you are right. Perhaps, I have to be content with expressions or some generic word, as there doesn't seem to be one word to express this sentiment. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The victimizer is feeling **rue** for having wronged the other party. In your example of India, the feeling arises from the realization that earlier actions may now make it harder if not impossible to obtain the victim's cooperation. Rue does not need to be contrite. In place of contrition, nation-states stress the win-win aspect of a rapprochement.

Comment: You are absolutely right in your understanding. In this case British state may *rue* for having wronged India in the past, because they *fear* that now India may be intractable for them and won't allow them to profit from Indian market. As you rightly said, their ruing a lost economic opportunity doesn't mean that British state feels contrite for its past actions in India. They rue because they fear Indian perverse response. How to describe this fear/paranoia?

Comment: I don't think you mean "describe".  You're looking for a single word. I'm suggesting that the word **rue** fits the behavior, or **ruefulness** if you want a noun.  It is not "paranoia", that is, not fear of an *imagined* threat, not an unwarranted fear.

Comment: It can be a term as well. Just like victim may suffer from a *victimisation complex*, a victimiser suffering from a complex where he feels that his victim may come after them, that paranoia.

Comment: Not sure why you keep psychologizing it as a complex. Nation-states don't have psyches.  That would be a figurative or metaphorical use of a technical term, if one existed.

Comment: India/britain or China/Japan was an example from Geopolitics which appeared in the British media here. It can be extended to individuals. I am not restricting it in any sense.

Comment: Is the concern warranted or unwarranted?  If it's warranted, it's not paranoia.

Comment: I would rather say the victimiser had his reasons to think so, but its unwarranted that's why it's a paranoia as there is an element of irrationality. If the victim starts acting in with some spite, then it's no longer a paranoia. I am focussing on the former part, as I mentioned in the question: *even though the victims have shown no such inclination.*

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "come after them".  That's pretty vague. Attack?

Comment: From *come after them* I mean that the victim chooses to adopt a punitive posture/policy towards his former scourge/victimiser.

Comment: They have an understandable but baseless fear of reprisal.  I am not aware of any overarching psychological term for this. It doesn't seem to fall into any category of psychological disorder. Ignorance of *Realpolitik* is not something you'd find in the DSM.

Comment: From DSM you mean *Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders*? I was not looking for some medical/mental term per se. But, if there is a one, good :) Well victimisation complex is not really a disorder, or? Just that people absorb some narrative and start believing them to be a perpetual victim. But it's more of a brain-washing, which can be unwashed by proper arguments, facts & figures.  Would we call it a disorder?

Comment: No, I don't think it's a disorder to be ready to believe that a country which one's own country has exploited or abused in the past is likely to be uncooperative in present times or at the very least a reticent ally.  It is simply a projection of the rules of human social interaction onto the geopolitical stage.

Comment: It was in interesting conversation with you. A lot of food of thought. Cheers! @mplungjan has posted an answer. Feel free to add your thoughts.